# model problems in vote system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models Vote, Option and Number. I set up an index to input voting information such as title and description. How do I store the number of votes (in the Number model) using radio buttons?

My models have the following attributes:

```
Vote: name, description
Option: vote_id, content
Number: option_id, content (integer)
```

here is my edit.html
i want to add vote-number function in this html,but i don't know how.so Can You give me some ideas to finish it? ^_^.i'm new in rails ,and thank you very much for helping me !!

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @vote.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @vote.description %>
</p>

    <%  for option in @vote.options %>


    <%=h option.content %><br />


<%  end %>



<%= link_to 'Back', votes_path %>
```

---

Comment: ^-^ i've post and please give some advise

Answer (score 0):

This might point you in the right direction:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

You'll want to use *fields_for* within your input form, and pass your second model to it.
Rails should take care of the magic in the backend if your model association relationships (belongs_to, has_many etc.) have been set up correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Using fields_for should create child rows in your child tables. Possibly you want to use AJAX (http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) to send data to the server. 

Do you have any code to post on here, or possibly github if it's a lot?

Comment: ^-^ i've post and please give some advise